# Synchronizing own tree list with GTK TreeView/TreeModel in Python

Tags: python, treeview, gtk3

In my application, I have a class that manages my tree (in brief, is like a filesystem ,where the root contains folders, that contains folder, etc. and also contains files). The problem I have now is that I have duplicated lists, i. e. the class that manages the filesystem, and separately, the TreeView/TreeModel, where I must create the tree using the data. This is needed, because my class has a lot more of methods and properties than the properties shown in the tree. For example, now, when I delete a file, I update my internal tree, and also have to remove the item from the TreeModel.

Is it possible to tell the TreeModel/TreeView to use my own class? Of course, I asume that I will have to modify the class that manages my tree, but what I would like to have is that when I add a file to a folder in my class, it would be automatically added to the TreeView, the same that when I remove it, or modify its name or properties.

Using Python 2.7.12, Ubuntu 16.04, Gtk3 (gi.repository, glade, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your class implement the TreeModel interface, and use it directly as the model, without having to synchronize between two classes at all!

Have your class extend `Gtk.TreeModel`, and implement its [virtual methods](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/interfaces/TreeModel.html#virtual-methods).

Comment: I have just seen the doc about `TreeModel`, but it has not any method to add/remove elements. Should I use `TreeStore` (that extends `TreeModel`) and has methods like `append`, `remove` and `clear`? If so, I don't see any documentation about virtual methods for `TreeStore`, so how could I do that? What about if I want to filter the tree?

Comment: `TreeStore` is a class, not an interface, so it doesn't have virtual methods. You might be able to extend `TreeStore` instead, but if you look at the implementation for `remove` in its [source code](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/gtk/gtktreestore.c#L1206), you will see that internally it uses `TreeModel`'s virtual methods like `do_row_deleted`.

Comment: To filter the tree, use a [`TreeModelFilter`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#Gtk-3.0/classes/TreeModelFilter.html#Gtk.TreeModelFilter).